# Call method from another class wihout making it static

Tags: c#, class, methods

I try to call a method from another class. Here is an example:

```
public class Students
{
    public void Printing()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(grade);
    }
}
```

And here is the Main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Students.Printing();
}
```

Visual Studio with the following exception: An object reference is required for the non-static field, a method to property 'Students.Printing()'. My question is how do I call **Printing** from **Main** without making it static?

Comment: You can't, if you want to call instance methods you need to have an instance.

Comment: Where does `grade` come from?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following without testing it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     new Students().Printing();
}
```

In static method you need to instantiate none static class to be able to access its members.